# Is there a CSS validator that is not as strict as W3C's that will validate things like normalize.css?

Tags: html, css, validation, html5boilerplate

I am using H5BP and I'm looking for a way to debug my CSS, however, W3C's CSS Validator returns errors for H5BP's normalize.css as well as main.css.

Is there something I can use to check for syntax errors that will validate normalize.css and main.css?

Also, what is the reason for not using the following line of code on normalize.css and main.css:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE:

In the end, my question comes down to biting the bullet and either separating my CSS code from the boilerplate's or deleting things I may not need.  This question helped me get there:

[HTML5 Boilerplate, HTML5 Reset CSS validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624808/html5-boilerplate-html5-reset-css-validation?rq=1)

Comment: Just a simple search on Google will show you some validators. This should help http://bit.ly/YQ5Thk

Comment: Do you know of one which will validate normalize.css?

Comment: Did you click on the link?

Comment: No need to be rude, friend.

Comment: I am not trying to be rude. I am sorry. But any of those validators will work. Try CSS lint. It has features you can turn off when validating

Comment: As for the charset, this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526033/why-specify-charset-utf-8-in-your-css-file

Comment: I do understand what the UTF-8 declaration accomplishes, however, I am wondering why, if anyone would know, the h5bp team has chosen to NOT include that when I am so used to including it.  The reason I am asking this, is because I have a dozen "parsing" errors in my css.  90% of them come from the default normalize.css and main.css style sheets, however, the validator includes some of my code as parsing errors as well and I am wondering if I have a better way of detecting errors besides separating the styles I wrote and the default styles from the boilerplate.

Comment: Also, the UTF-8 declaration does not fix the problem.  Do you know what a parsing error is?  I've searched forever trying to find out how I would be able to fix an issue, all of which pointed me to the UTF-8 declaration, however, like I pointed out above, it was not solved.

Comment: But, I guess my question was answered through here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624808/html5-boilerplate-html5-reset-css-validation?rq=1

Comment: You should put that information in your questions

Comment: Why don't you post your thoughts in an answer below and I'll give you credit for your help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

In the end, my question comes down to biting the bullet and either separating my CSS code from the boilerplate's or deleting things I may not need. This question helped me get there:

[HTML5 Boilerplate, HTML5 Reset CSS validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624808/html5-boilerplate-html5-reset-css-validation)

Answer (score 2):

A good tool that I have used in the past is [CSS Lint](http://www.csslint.net). It is a very good validation tool, as there are different errors and warnings that you can turn off and on. There is also one for javascript, called [JS Lint](http://www.jslint.com).

As for the charset part, if you want to know what it is used for, then this question has been answered here
[Why specify @charset "UTF-8"; in your CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526033/why-specify-charset-utf-8-in-your-css-file)

Hope this helps you.